# SwiftUI VStack spacing: not working properly

Tags: swift, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI VStack that sits inside a scrollView, a Geometry reader and a NavigationView, here is the code:

```
struct RezeptList: View {

    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: ColorScheme
    @EnvironmentObject private var recipeStore: RecipeStore

    @State private var searching = false
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State private var showingAddRecipeView = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            GeometryReader { geo in
                ScrollView {
                    SearchBar(searchText: self.$searchText, isSearching: self.$searching)
                    VStack(spacing: 30) {

                        ForEach(self.recipeStore.recipes.filter{$0.name.hasPrefix(self.searchText) || self.searchText == ""}) {recipe in
                            NavigationLink(destination:
                            RezeptDetail(recipe: recipe).environmentObject(self.recipeStore)) {
                                Card(rezept: recipe,width: geo.size.width - 20)
                            }
                            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                        }

                        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                            self.showingAddRecipeView = true
                        }){
                            Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
                                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                            }
                        .padding()
                        )
                    }
                    .padding(.bottom)
                    .navigationBarTitle("Rezepte")
                    .sheet(isPresented: self.$showingAddRecipeView) {
                        AddRecipeView(isPresented: self.$showingAddRecipeView)
                            .environmentObject(self.recipeStore)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    init() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.label
    }

}
```

But it looks like this no matter the amount of spacing:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cllt.png)

But I noticed when I move the .navigationBarItems modifiers it works but then as soon as you tap on the navigationLink the app crashes.

Answer (score 1):

`SwiftUI` sometimes has weird behavior issues with the placement of some modifiers.

In your case, if you move `.navigationBarItems` to after `navigationBarTitle`, it should fix this issue and you will get back your `VStack` spacing.

```
.navigationBarTitle("Rezepte")
.navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
    self.showingAddRecipeView = true
}, label: {
    Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
        .foregroundColor(.primary)
}).padding())
```

Besides, I have observed that it's better to have these navigation related modifiers closer to the `NavigationView` than deep within the hierarchy.

---

#### Example (based on your view hierarchy):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isShowing: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { (geo) in
                ScrollView {
                    VStack(spacing: 60) {
                        ForEach(0...10, id:\.self) { (index) in
                            NavigationLink(destination: Text(String(index))) {
                                Text("Button")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationBarTitle("Title")
                    .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                        self.isShowing = true
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
                    }))
                    .sheet(isPresented: self.$isShowing) {
                        Button(action: {
                            self.isShowing = false
                        }) {
                            Text("Dismiss")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I doesn't work if I move the navigationBarItemsModifier down the nested view of the navigationLink instantly dismisses itself onAppear

Comment: @EichenherzMo I tested this answer in a playground and it works to fix the `spacing` issue. However, the sheet being dismissed automatically seems to be another issue. Maybe `AddRecipeView` is setting `showingAddRecipeView` back to false `onAppear`.

Comment: thx for helping I fixed it myself by modifying the ForEach to this: ```ForEach(0..<recipeStore.recipes.count, id: \.self){ number in
                        NavigationLink(destination: RezeptDetail(recipe: self.recipeStore.recipes[number]).environmentObject(self.recipeStore)) {
                            Card(recipe: self.recipeStore.recipes[number], width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 30)
                        }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    }